# A sequence $(x_n)$ does not converge to $p$ if and only if there is a neighborhood around $p$ that contains finitely many $x_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in the metric space $(M,d)$ and let $p$ be an arbitrary point in $M$. I want to prove the following statement which seems intuitively reasonable to me (please check it out though).

> A sequence $(x_n)$ does not converge to $p$ if and only if there is a neighborhood around $p$ that contains finitely many $x_n$.

I preferred to prove the contra-positive form which seems easier.

> A sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $p$ if and only if every neighborhood around $p$ contains infinitely many $x_n$.

Let me write down the statements in a symbolic form. A sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $p$ means that

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\quad\exists N \in \mathbb{N},\quad \forall n,\quad n\ge N \rightarrow d(x_n,p)<\epsilon.$$

Every neighborhood around $p$ contains infinitely many $x_n$ is equivalent to
$$\forall r>0,\quad \exists\, \text{infinitely many $n$},\quad d(x_n,p)<r.$$

The proof for $(\Rightarrow)$ is obvious. Let $r$ be given, then by choosing $\epsilon=r$ for every $n\ge N$ we get $d(x_n,p)<r$ which means that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $d(x_n,p)<r$.

The proof for $(\Leftarrow)$ is not that much obvious to me. Can someone help me with this or give me a hint. Also, that would be fine if you want to prove the original statement directly rather than using its contra-positive form.

Comment: The sequence $x_n=(-1)^n+\frac1n$ does not converge to $p=1$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Ooops! Nice counter example! Thanks. :)

Comment: Let every $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of p contain infinitely many indices $n$  with $|x_n-p| < \epsilon.$ Then p is a limit point of $x_n$, a subsequence converges to p. Choosing $x_n=(-1)^n$ shows that $x_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse statement $(\Leftarrow)$ is generally not true. As  Hagen von Eitzen mentioned the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}$ has infinitely many terms around $1$ and $-1$ and it converges to none of them! However, it can be proved that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence to $p$.

Then the corrected original statement is

> If there is no subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $p$ then there is a neighborhood around $p$ that contains finitely many $x_n$.

and its equivalent contra-positive form will be

> If every neighborhood around $p$  contains infinitely many $x_n$ then there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $p$.

The proof for this is easy. If we choose $r=\frac{1}{k}$ then for each $k$ we can find an $n_k$ such that $d(x_{n_k},p)<\frac{1}{k}$. As there are infinitely many terms in every neighborhood of $p$, we can also ensure that $n_1<n_2<\dots$ so $x_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ that converges to $p$.

The corrected original statement is used in Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis. Specifically, in Chatper 2, Theorem 27 which aims to show $[a, b]$ is compact and Theorem 63 which wants to prove sequentially compact is equivalent to covering compact.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Let $x_n=1$ for $n$ even and $-1$ for $n$ odd. Then $(x_n)$ does not converge to $1$ but every neighborhood of $1$ contains $x_n$ for  infinitely many values of $n$.